# how to modify a column of numpy arrays stored in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays and want to modify some numbers of arrays. This is my simplified list:

```
first_list=[np.array([[1.,2.,0.], [2.,1.,0.], [6.,8.,3.], [8.,9.,7.]]),
            np.array([[1.,0.,2.], [0.,0.,2.], [5.,5.,1.], [0.,6.,2.]])]
```

I have a factor which defines how many splits I have in each arrays:

```
spl_array=2.
```

it means each array of the list can be splited into 2 ones. I want to add a fixed value (`3.`) into last column of each split of each array and also copy the last split and subtract this value (`3.`) from the third column of this copied split. Finally I want to have it as following:

```
final_list=[np.array([[1.,2.,3.], [2.,1.,3.], [6.,8.,6.], [8.,9.,10.], \
                      [6.,8.,0.], [8.,9.,4.]]), # copied and subtracted
            np.array([[1.,0.,5.], [0.,0.,5.], [5.,5.,4.], [0.,6.,5.], \
                      [5.,5.,-2.], [0.,6.,-1.]])] # copied and subtracted
```

I tried some for loops but I totaly lost. In advance , I do appreciate any help.

```
final_list=[]
for i in first_list:
    each_lay=np.split (i, spl_array)
    for j in range (len(each_lay)):
        final_list.append([each_lay[j][:,0], each_lay[j][:,1], each_lay[j][:,2]+3])
```

Comment: I don't understand how do you obtain 0, 0, -2, -1. Can you explain me please? I thought 0, 4, -2, -1

Comment: Dear @Corralien, it was partly my bad. First `0` should be `4.` Lets explain it. Value of last column of last split of first array are `3.` and `7.`, I copied this split and subtracted the last column by `3.`, so, last column of copied split will be `0` and `4.`. For the second array the last column of last split is `1.` and `2.`, so if I subtract `3.` from them it will be `-2.` and `-1.`.

Comment: are all the arrays in the list the same?

Comment: Dear @yan ziselman, yes, all the arrays have the same length. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: is there a reason you don't stack all the array in a single array?

Comment: Dear @yan ziselman,If I stack all of them, then I do not how to copy some splits. As I mentioned, I am copying the last split of each array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you expect:

```
m = np.asarray(first_list)
m = np.concatenate((m, m[:, 2:]), axis=1)

m[:, :4, 2] += 3
m[:, 4:, 2] -= 3

final_list = m.tolist()
```

```
>>> m
array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  2.,   1.,   3.],
        [  6.,   8.,   6.],
        [  8.,   9.,  10.],
        [  6.,   8.,   0.],
        [  8.,   9.,   4.]],
       [[  1.,   0.,   5.],
        [  0.,   0.,   5.],
        [  5.,   5.,   4.],
        [  0.,   6.,   5.],
        [  5.,   5.,  -2.],
        [  0.,   6.,  -1.]]])
```